# How to get the value of a variable when you cant debug or use console.log()

Tags: javascript, debugging, directory, path, console.log

I am trying to find where this extension I installed is storing the templates that are made. I want to know this and HOW they are stored so that I can change the code so that there is a specific template made within the extension itself. A default extension.

I think ive located where the directory for the templates is made but I cant seem to debug or console.log to get the value of this path. I believe the path will be the variable templateDir thats within the TemplatesManager.prototype.getTemplates function...

here is the templatesManager.js file so you can see how that variable is made.

It would be helpful if someone could help me understand how to obtain the value of that variable. I tried console.log(templateDir) but nothing pops up on the VS Code terminal, output, or any other console window.

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var os = require('os');
/**
 * Main class to handle the logic of the File Templates
 * @export
 * @class TemplatesManager
 */
var TemplatesManager = (function () {
    function TemplatesManager(config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    /**
     * Returns a list of available file templates by reading the Templates Directory.
     * @returns string[]
     */
    TemplatesManager.prototype.getTemplates = function () {
        // @TODO make this async (use promises ???)
        var templateDir = this.getTemplatesDir();
        var templateFiles = fs.readdirSync(templateDir).map(function (item) {
            if (!/^\./.exec(item)) {
                return fs.statSync(path.join(templateDir, item)).isFile() ? item : null;
            }
            return null;
        }).filter(function (filename) {
            return filename !== null;
        });
        return templateFiles;
    };
    /**
     * Read the contents of a templates
     * @param filename The name of the template file.
     * @return Buffer
     */
    TemplatesManager.prototype.getTemplate = function (filename) {
        return fs.readFileSync(path.join(this.getTemplatesDir(), filename), 'utf8');
    };
    /**
     * Returns the templates directory location.
     * If no user configuration is found, the extension will look for
     * templates in USER_DATA_DIR/Code/FileTemplates.
     * Otherwise it will look for the path defined in the extension configuration.
     * @return {string}
     */
    TemplatesManager.prototype.getTemplatesDir = function () {
        return this.config.get('templates_dir', this.getDefaultTemplatesDir());
    };
    /**
     * Returns the default templates location based on the user OS.
     * @returns {string}
     */
    TemplatesManager.prototype.getDefaultTemplatesDir = function () {
        var userDataDir = null;
        switch (process.platform) {
            case 'linux':
                userDataDir = path.join(os.homedir(), '.config');
                break;
            case 'darwin':
                userDataDir = path.join(os.homedir(), 'Library', 'Application Support');
                break;
            case 'win32':
                userDataDir = process.env.APPDATA;
                break;
            default:
                throw Error("Unrecognizable operative system");
        }
        return path.join(userDataDir, 'Code', 'User', 'FileTemplates');
        
    };
    /**
     * Creates the templates dir if not exists
     * @throw Error
     */
    TemplatesManager.prototype.createTemplatesDirIfNotExists = function () {
        var templatesDir = this.getTemplatesDir();
        fs.mkdir(templatesDir, '0755', function (err) {
            if (err && err.code != 'EEXIST') {
                throw Error("Failed to created templates directory " + templatesDir);
            }
        });
    };
    return TemplatesManager;
}());
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = TemplatesManager;
//# sourceMappingURL=templatesManager.js.map
```

Comment: `theVariable` may not have a value. Use `console.log(theVariable || 'no dice')` to check for that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion theVariable was just a place holder. as i have tried to console.log() different instances of the path in different functions. it seems to get created by a function and then returned a few times over until it get set to the variable templateDir.  I have console.log() on those different names for the same path. the issue is that when i console.log(ANYTHING), nothing shows up.